# Drag and drop image functionality for adding images in RefineryCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms

In RefineryCMS, for image upload present functionality is to browse the image and then click to upload the image.

Is it possible to add drag and drop image functionality to page image ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try dropzone: http://www.dropzonejs.com/

You'll need to override refinery's backend and see how image upload actions are handled.